# How can I use NSString between classes?

Tags: objective-c, class, nsstring

I have two classes, Class A and Class B, both of them are subclasses of UIViewController.

I class A I have an NSString and I want to use this NSString in class B.

ClassA.h:

```
@class ClassB;
@interface ClassA : UIViewController {
   ClassB *classB;
   NSString stringA;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) ClassB *classB;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *stringA;

@end
```

ClassA.m:

```
stringA = [NSString stringWithString:webView.request.URL.absoluteString];
```

ClassB.h:

```
@class ClassA;
@interface ClassA : UIViewController {
   ClassB *classA;
   NSString stringB;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) ClassB *classA;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *stringB;

@end
```

ClassB.m:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { 
self.stringB = classA.stringA;
}
```

Of course I did #import for both classes.
For some reason I always get NULL I classB for stringB.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to comment one thing you have high probability of RetainLoop, while ClassA retains ClassB and ClassB retains ClassA. When do they release?

Second thing, in:

ClassA.m:

`stringA = [NSString stringWithString:webView.request.URL.absoluteString];`

change to:

`self.stringA = [NSString stringWithString:webView.request.URL.absoluteString];`

while object returned by [NSString stringWithString:] is set to autorelease, and you need to retain it to be sure that you have valid instance of string.

Please provide more code.

Comment: Thank you for helping, thats the most relevant code that I can provide

Answer (score 1):

The following aren't clear:

- is `mainViewController` actually an instance of `ClassA`?
- is `classA` even an instance of `ClassA`, as you've declared it an instance of `ClassB`?
- what is your real code, as the things you've pasted here don't compile?
- when in the `ClassA` object's lifecycle do you initialise `stringA`?
- did that occur before you tried to use it in your `ClassB` object?

Comment: 1. I'm sorry, I edited the code because I have changed it to ClassA and ClassB.
2. No.
4. I didn't initialise stringA

Comment: If you haven't initialised stringA, why is it surprising that its value is nil when assigned to stringB?

Comment: Actually I did initialised the string,
Here's how the string gets it's code:


- (void)shareLeftAction:(id)sender {
 self.stringA = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
 [self presentModalViewController:sharingController animated:YES];
}


Then an UIViewController is presented with the string value.